# TextArea wordWrap for mail

Tags: php, email, yii

I'm using phpMailer in my project , and passing the message/body via a CHtml textArea.

However , long mails are not being send (or when I used just mail() , the message was empty)

Now , when I write a message in the code , with \n all is fine.

So fom that I conclude that the textArea is not breaking the lines (gets over 70) , I tried using word-wrap but it seems like not working.

Here's pat of my mailer:

```
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->Subject = ($_GET['subject']);
$mail->MsgHTML($_GET['message']);                                       
$mail->AddAddress(Person::model()->findByPk($id)->email);
$mail->Send();
```

and here is the textArea:

```
 <?php echo CHtml::textArea('message','message. . . ',array('id'=>'message','style'=>'text-align: right','cols'=>75)); ?>
```

Does anyone know where is the problem?

Thanks , Mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is not being passed *via* but from the `textarea` and via an HTTP GET request which probably is one of the problems since the total length of a GET request body is limited to 1024 characters.

The `WordWrap` addribut tells the mailer to break the body text at every nth character with a newline so you don't have to worry about that. Just make it a POST.

Comment: Changed the get to post like this: `$mail->MsgHTML($_POST['message']);` Now the mail is not being sent at all.

Comment: Now you're reading POST variables for a GET request (which I assume it is). Change the request to be of method POST! I.e. an HTML form with method="POST" and a submit button should send the data.

Comment: True , turns out that `url:"'.CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('Person/senderAll')).'",` is sending in GET. Is there a way so send it with POST?

Answer (score 0):

ok , problem solved.

Here's my new ajax:

```
$.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            data:{checked:checked,subject:subject,message:message},
                            url:"'.$url.'",
                            success:function(){window.location="index.php?r=person/admin"},                 
                    });
```

And in the controlle , i changed all the `_GET` to `_POST`